# Does $u(x)=0$ the only one function which satisfy series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Agree or disagree $u(x)=0$ the only one function which satisfy
$$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty} u(x)r^{x}=0$$
($0< r< 1$, and $u(x)$ may containing $r$)?

I think if $u(x)=c$ ($c$ is constant) can't satisfy the equation.

If $u(x)=x$, $u(x)=x^2$, $u(x)=x^3, \ldots$  can't satisfy the equation.

Comment: What is the domain of $u$? What about $u(x) = \sin(\pi x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u(x)$ may depend on $r$ then the answer is NO. Take $u(x)=\frac {f(x)} {r^{x}}$ where $\sum f(x)=0$ but $f$ not identically $0$.

If $u(x)$ does not depend on $r$ then the answer is YES.

The coefficients of a power series with positive radius of convergence are uniquely determined, so  we get $u(x)=0$ for all $x$.